# Doctrine2 Multiple DBs without Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, composer-php, dbal

I know that using the Doctrinebundle in Symfony2 it is possible to instantiate multiple DB connections under Doctrine...

```
$connectionFactory = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');
$connection = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'foo_user',
    'password' => 'foo_pass',
    'host'     => 'foo_host',
    'dbname'   => 'foo_db',
));
```

I'm curious if this is the case if you are using PURELY Doctrine though?, I've set up Doctrine via Composer like so...

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "lib/"
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.4"
    }
}
```

And have been looking for my `ConnectionFactory` class but am not seeing it anywhere? Am I required to use Symfony2 to do this?

Should I just download [ConnectionFactory.php](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/ConnectionFactory.php) from the DoctrineBundle and include it in my DBAL folder?? idk?

Comment: Is it a Symfony2/Doctrine question or just a Doctrine question?

Comment: @ThomasPotaire Just a Doctrine question, but its using a Symfony bundle class as an example of how it was done before.

Comment: ping, you got an answer ;)

Comment: @Pazi sorry was out of the office for the 4th ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle is only in the context of symfony needed, it wraps the orm into symfony infrastructure (services, etc.). For pure use of the orm you should read the **[ORM: Installation and Configuration](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)**. As you see you must create an entity manager by yourself with `EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config)`, so simply create different entity managers for your different databases.

For DBAL use you should read **[DBAL: Configuration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)** and see, a connection can simply obtained trough `DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);` But if you are sure the `ConnectionFactory` has no dependency to symfony stuff **and you really need it**, you can try copy it to your code and construct a new factory to obtain a DBAL connection.

```
$connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(array());
$connection = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'foo_user',
    'password' => 'foo_pass',
    'host'     => 'foo_host',
    'dbname'   => 'foo_db',
));
```

But take care, this is a **DBAL connection**, i.e. it's a abstraction layer which sits on top of PDO and only for pure SQL queries. If you need a entity manager you have to initialize it as mentioned in the docs above, or maybe you find another entity manager factory class, which you can "copy".

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no `ConnectionFactory class` inside the A-typical installation of Doctrine2. There is the class in the Symfony2 bundle, but porting is required. The main catch is in the constructor `array $typesConfig` but I have no idea what they're actually asking for, I assumed the magic.conf types, but evidently this isn't the case...

Comment: As I said, you can copy it. In a standard symfony installation it seems the `$typesConfig` is an empty array. But where's the difference between simply calling `DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config)`?